# Memory allocation for an array of objects

Tags: c++, object, memory-management

I have a class.My code compiles correctly,but when I`m trying to enter this array from a keyboard my program stops working.I think the problem is in memory allocation.How to allocate the memory properly to solve this problem?

```
class group
{
    protected:
        diplomStudent *arr;
        int size;
    public:
        group(int studs)
        {
            arr=new diplomStudent[studs];
            size=studs;
        }
        void setgroup()
        {
            for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
                cin>>arr[i];//'>>' is overloaded for diplomstudent 
        }
     }
```

Overloaded operation;

```
friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, diplomStudent& obj)
    {

         is >> obj.surname;
         is >> obj.name;
         is >> obj.patr;
         is >> obj.course;
         is >> obj.rate;
         is >> obj.diplom;
         is >> obj.perscent;
         return is;
    }
```

Main function:

```
int main()
{
group g1(2);
    g1.setgroup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting? The code you posted doesn't seem to be relevant at first sight. Please also post the definition of `diplomStudent`. PS: You code leaks `group::app` which is not deleted anywhere.

Comment: The memory *is* allocated for `diplomStudent`. But if your teacher is silly enough to prevent you from using `std::string`, and instead `obj.surname` is a raw pointer that points at nothing, you'll have undefined behavior in your program (a crash is one possibility for UB). This is just speculation on my part, you didn't provide a proper [mcve] for anyone to know how you messed up.

Comment: About the memory allocation, the preferred way is to use a vector for this, but code for allocating via new [] doesn't seems like the culprit.  However, we don't know what diplomStudent is, so we can't help with that but the standard procedure for these sort of problems is to go through the code with a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

The problem must be in the definition of the class diplomStudent, but since you don't provide that information we can not be sure. I'm using a string for all of the members of the class and is working just fine for me, here you have the sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class diplomStudent
{
public:
    string surname, name, patr, course, rate, diplom, perscent;
    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, diplomStudent& obj)
    {
        is >> obj.surname; is >> obj.name; is >> obj.patr; is >> obj.course;
        is >> obj.rate; is >> obj.diplom; is >> obj.perscent;
        return is;
    }
};

class group
{
protected:
    diplomStudent *arr;
    int size;
public:
    group(int studs) : arr(new diplomStudent[studs]), size(studs) {}
    ~group() { delete[] arr; }

    void setGroup()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            cin >> arr[i];          //'>>' is overloaded for diplomStudent 
    }

    void printGroup()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            cout << arr[i].surname << " " << arr[i].name << " " << arr[i].patr << " " << arr[i].course
            << " " << arr[i].rate << " " << arr[i].diplom << " " << arr[i].perscent << endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    group g1(2);
    g1.setGroup();
    g1.printGroup();
    return 0;
}
```